# Table or view not found - Spark Scala

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm beginner with big data and i'm working with spark-scala. I work with dataframes and to make things clear to me I used multiple scala objects to write my code. all the classes have main methods to run the code. The first scala object is used to load files into dataframes and the other scala objects make statistics computations. this is some of the code of the first one

```
object LoadFiles {



  //classes for datasets

  case class T(X: Option[String], P: Option[String],Y:Option[String])
     println("Load File 1 into dataframe")

def main(args: Array[String]){

 val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "LoadFiles1") 
 val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
 val warehouseLocation = new File("spark-warehouse").getAbsolutePath
 val spark = SparkSession
 .builder()
 .appName("Spark Hive Example")
 .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
 .enableHiveSupport()
 .getOrCreate()


import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType,StructField,StringType};


  val dataframe1 = sc.textFile("file1.ttl").map(_.split(" |\\ . ")).map(p => 
 T(Try(p(0).toString()).toOption,Try(p(1).toString()).toOption,Try(p(2).toString()).toOption)).toDF()


  dataframe1
  .write
  .partitionBy("Predicate")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .saveAsTable("dataframe1")
   }}
```

The other scala objects are used to make many computations from the loaded dataframes and create other dataframes

this is the second one

```
object Statistics1 {


  def main(args: Array[String]) {
     val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "LoadFiles1") 
     val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
     val warehouseLocation = new File("spark-warehouse").getAbsolutePath
     val spark = SparkSession
     .builder()
     .appName("Spark Hive Example")
     .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
     .enableHiveSupport()
     .getOrCreate()


import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType,StructField,StringType};


   // subject query
    val Query1 = spark.sql("SELECT X As Res, P as Pred, COUNT(Y) As nbrFROM dataframe1 GROUP BY X, P")
    .write
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .saveAsTable("stat1") }}
```

I got the error `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: dataframe1; line 1 pos 75`

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Check if the table exists in warehouseLocation directory.

Comment: Hi, can you print out the dataframe1 rows before saving it as a Hive table?

Comment: @JiayiLiao Yes the table exists in warehouseLocation directory

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis I'm not sure I think yes

Comment: HelIo, I mean if you can print it out and post the results here? I am curious to see the content of the dataframe with all these options you have in there :)

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis you can find it here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55121544/splitting-ttl-or-nt-file-spark-scala