# Splitting .ttl or .nt file - Spark Scala

Tags: apache-spark, split, semantic-web

I'm new to scala and I need to read line by line a ttl file and split on particular delimiter and extract values to put in respective columns in dataframe.

```
< http://website/Jimmy_Carter> <http://web/name> "James Earl Carter, Jr."@ko .
< http://website/Jimmy_Car> <http://web/country> <http://website/United_States> .
< http://website/Jimmy_Car> <http://web/birthPlace> <http://web/Georgia_(US)> .
```

I want to have this output

```
+-------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------
|S                              |P                          |O                                                             |
+-------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------

|http://website/Jimmy_Car       |http://web/name            |"James Earl Carter                                                       |
|http:///website/Jimmy_Car      |http://web/country         |http://web/country                   |
|http://website/Jimmy_Car       |http://web/birthPlace      |http://web/Georgia_(US)             |
|
```

I tried this code

```
case class T(S: Option[String], P: Option[String],O:Option[String])


 val triples = sc.textFile("triples_test.ttl").map(_.split(" |\\< |\\> |\\ . ")).map(p => 
  T(Try(p(0).toString()).toOption,Try(p(1).toString()).toOption,Try(p(2).toString()).toOption)).toDF()
```

And I got this result

```
    +-------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------
|S                              |P                          |O                                                             |
+-------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------

|<http://website/Jimmy_Car       |<http://web/name            |"James                                                       |
|<http:///website/Jimmy_Car      |<http://web/country         |<http://web/country                   |
|<http://website/Jimmy_Car       |<http://web/birthPlace      |<http://web/Georgia_(US)
```

To remove the separator "<" in the begin of each triple I added "|<" to the split

```
 val triples = sc.textFile("triples_test.ttl").map(_.split(" |\\< |\\> |\\ . |<")).map(p => 
  T(Try(p(0).toString()).toOption,Try(p(1).toString()).toOption,Try(p(2).toString()).toOption)).toDF()
```

And I had this result result

```
    +-------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------
|S                              |P                          |O                                                             |
+-------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------

|                                |http://web/name            |                                                      |
|                                |http://web/country         |                   |
|                                |http://web/birthPlace      |
```

How can I solve this problem

Comment: Hi @NTH I change the code into Scala in the case you were not able to execute it! Good luck

Comment: Hello @AlexandrosBiratsis, thank you so much ! Because I'm beginner with scala programming and I didn't work with python either. but I forgot a détail in my problem. In the 3rd column of dataframe (the O column) I only need data that started with "http ://web/ ". So according to the example I don't need to put all the line of the file that contain "James Earl Carter" in the dataframe.

Comment: Then you have to remove the part of the regex responsible for that :) you just need to slightly change the url_regex only. Give it a try you gonna need them and is very powerful tool...

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis No I didn't remove it because I need it but I added this line of code "val DF = dfA.filter($"Object".contains("http ://web/"))" . Thanks a lot :)

Comment: very good then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below the answer in the case that is not clear how to replace your code with the build-in regex functionality in Spark. Although you need to be sure that you understand how regex work before using this approach.

```
val df = Seq(
        ("< http://website/Jimmy_Carter>", "<http://web/name>", "\"James Earl Carter, Jr.\"@ko .\""),
        ("< http://website/Jimmy_Car>", "<http://web/country>", "<http://website/United_States> ."),
        ("< http://website/Jimmy_Car>", "<http://web/birthPlace>", "<http://web/Georgia_(US)> .")
    ).toDF("S", "P", "O")

val url_regex = """^(?:"|<{1}\s?)(.*)(?:>(?:\s\.)?|,\s.*)$"""
val dfA = df.withColumn("S", regexp_extract($"S", url_regex, 1))
            .withColumn("P", regexp_extract($"P", url_regex, 1))
            .withColumn("O", regexp_extract($"O", url_regex, 1))
```

This will output:

```
+---------------------------+---------------------+----------------------------+
|S                          |P                    |O                           |
+---------------------------+---------------------+----------------------------+
|http://website/Jimmy_Carter|http://web/name      |James Earl Carter           |
|http://website/Jimmy_Car   |http://web/country   |http://website/United_States|
|http://website/Jimmy_Car   |http://web/birthPlace|http://web/Georgia_(US)     |
+---------------------------+---------------------+----------------------------+
```

Just a little explanation how the regex works even if this is not the subject of the post.

1. `(?:"|<{1}\s?)` Identify rows that start with `"` or `<` or `<`
2. `(.*)` extract content of the matches into the 1st group
3. `(?:>(?:\s\.)?|,\s.*)` Identify rows that end either with `>` or `> .` or `,\s.*` the last for the James Earl case

Answer (score 0):

You can't read a Turtle file like this. Plus, regex is a very naive way of reading N-Triples. Don't reinvent the wheel and use https://github.com/banana-rdf/banana-rdf